# Server unable to capture the POST data sent from another server by URL redirect

Tags: php, post

Recently i started working on the Payment Gateway( further spelled as '**PG**') process for my site. The process involves sending the **Post data** by form to **PG** server by redirecting to their page, and receiving a response from the **PG** about the Transaction via **POST data** sent by redirecting the URL to our server page.

The problem arises here, as my server unable to retrieve the POST Data sent from **PG** server.

As I am coding in PHP, I tried to print all the response coming from **PG** with `print_r($_POST);` and even tried with `print_r($_REQUEST);`. I didn't find any data printing except the `PHPSESSID` and some other data array.

As for the confirmation I checked whether they were sending the Data or not with the IE addon known as "**TamperIE**". It is showing all the POST data sending to their server. But it is not at all coming to our server. I tried this process on another Server: there I was able to get the POST response, but not with currently working server.

Can you suggest what might be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the error log? Is the PG accessing your page and you're just not receiving any data or doesn't it access your server at all?

Comment: do you have any mod_rewrite rule which may apply on the destination file before/while PG server trying to reach that file?

Comment: Can u check the header details of the request /responses and see whether the data is available?

Comment: Dear Mahdi, this is what my .htaccess file content..           Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A259200000
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2013 20:00:00 GMT"
</filesMatch>

Comment: Dear  user1599669, I checked the all request /responses details, there i unable to find any data except the PHPSESSID..

Comment: @user1749092 First I'd say update your question with these new info, then add an exception at top of your rewrite rules like `^pg_handler.php$` to make sure that your rewrite rules doesn't effect on your post-back mechanism. If one of you rewrite rules just redirect the requested page from PG gateway, then you will lose all the POST data, which seems similar to what you are struggling now ... you should be careful about this line: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.php` ... I guess your problem is somewhere here ...

Comment: Why not simulate the situation using curl ? and see what you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Simulate the request from the other server by using curl, make a test.php with the following content:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/path/to/form");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$data = array(
    'foo' => 'foo foo foo',
    'bar' => 'bar bar bar',
    'baz' => 'baz baz baz'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

And run it using cli to get the debugging information and see what is wrong. Don't forget offcourse to put the variables supposed to be returned from the server and the exact url

Comment: Dear Omar, Thanks for your Suggestion. I even Tried for above code which you have given. I still failed to get the Response.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why this issue is occurring.

In the *.htaccess* file I written the line for the Redirection:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If I remove the above line from the file, I am able to receive the POST Fields from *PG* server, But I am *loosing the SESSION DATA* stored before proceeding for *PG* contains the Booking Info. These session are unable to show in the response page, as server generating totally new session from the response page.

I found one alternate solution for this issue:

I am using the following code in all the pages which require the session as:

```
$lifetime=60*30;
session_set_cookie_params ( $lifetime , '/', '.mysite.com');
```

After adding above code before `session_start();`.

Now I am able to get both POST data from *PG* and also able to *retain the SESSION Values*.

However, I think this is not an ideal solution for this issue. If anyone can suggest any SERVER Configuration for the URL Redirection and maintaining the SESSION values after REDIRECTION it will be great. Thank you All :-)

Answer (score 0):

If possible send a unique code (order id) of your sales/purchase order in PG request and I'm sure your PG will send back that unique code in the POST data and with the help of that unique code you can track that order id to update the status of the order.

By using this approach you do not need to worry about the session.

Answer (score 0):

Use CURl for this, its secure and reliable.

Comment: He can't: form submission takes place on the *client*, not on the server.